# How to delete a string from a text file?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, regex

I currently have two strings assigned - domain,subdomain

How could I delete any matched occurrences of these strings in a text file?

```
string domain = "127.0.0.1 test.com"
string subdomain = "127.0.0.1 sub.test.com"
```

I don't think using a regex would be ideal in this situation.

How can this be done?

Comment: So, what's the question. How to recognize these strings?  Needs more examples.  How to remove strings/lines from a text file? Needs more details.

Comment: Find a windows version of sed. Perfect tool for the job. Also, what makes you think regular expressions aren't suitable?

Answer (score 5):

You need to:

- Open the existing file for input
- Open a new file for output
- Repeatedly:

  - Read a line of text from the input
  - See if it matches your pattern (it's unclear at the moment what pattern you're looking for)
  - If it *doesn't*, write the line to the output (or if you're only trying to remove *bits* of lines, work out which bit you want to write out)
- Close both the input and output (a `using` statement will do this automatically)
- Optionally delete the original file and rename the new one if you want to effectively replace the original.

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText("file.txt"),
    @"127\.0\.0\.1 test\.com|127\.0\.0\.1 sub\.test\.com", string.Empty);
```

Then write to file obtained result.